# implementar transaction en VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, .net

Se puede ejecutar commit o rollback de una transaccion A al ejecutar exitosamente una transaccion B?, si la transaccion B no es exitosa lo que quiero hacer es un rollback de todo, ya que intento de la siguiente forma pero el commit de la transaccion A no se realiza

```html
Public Sub Guardar(ByVal operacion As String, ByVal clvSesion As Integer, ByVal importeEfectivo As Decimal, ByVal importeCambio As Decimal,
                   ByVal Contrato As Int64, ByVal Cajera As String, ByVal Sucursal As Int32, ByVal Caja As Int32,
                   ByVal Tipo As String)

    Try

        Dim sqlTranPago As SqlTransaction
        Dim sqlTranFactura As SqlTransaction

        If operacion = "Pago" Then
            Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MiConexion)
                cnn.Open()
                sqlTranPago = cnn.BeginTransaction()

                Try
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GrabaPago", cnn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Transaction = sqlTranPago

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gloClv_Session", clvSesion)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efectivo", importeEfectivo)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cambio", importeCambio)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    'sqlTranPago.Commit()

                    cnn.Close()
                    cnn.Dispose()

                Catch ex As Exception
                    sqlTranPago.Rollback()
                End Try

            End Using
        ElseIf operacion = "Factura" Then
            Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MiConexion)
                cnn.Open()
                'Dim sqlTran As SqlTransaction = cnn.BeginTransaction()
                sqlTranFactura = cnn.BeginTransaction()

                Try
                    Dim Clv_FacturaSalida1 As Int64
                    Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GrabaFactura", cnn)
                    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
                    cmd.Transaction = sqlTranFactura

                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrato", Contrato)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clv_Session", clvSesion)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cajera", Cajera)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sucursal", Sucursal)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caja", Caja)
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", Tipo)

                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                    sqlTranFactura.Commit()
                    sqlTranPago.Commit()
                    GloClv_Factura = cmd.Parameters("@Clv_FacturaSalida").Value

                    cnn.Close()
                    cnn.Dispose()
                Catch ex As Exception
                    sqlTranFactura.Rollback()
                    sqlTranPago.Rollback()
                End Try

            End Using
        End If

    Catch ex As Exception

    End Try

End Sub
```

Comment: Si se puede yo lo he realizado pero si puedes hacerlo todo dentro de un solo SP. Ese es el camino correcto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acuerdp a lo que preguntas, deberia quedar algo más o menos así pero como te comente deberias meter toda la logica en un solo SP.

```
Public Sub Guardar(ByVal operacion As String, ByVal clvSesion As Integer, ByVal importeEfectivo As Decimal, ByVal importeCambio As Decimal,
                   ByVal Contrato As Int64, ByVal Cajera As String, ByVal Sucursal As Int32, ByVal Caja As Int32,
                   ByVal Tipo As String)



    Dim sqlTrans As SqlTransaction


    Using cnn As SqlConnection = New SqlConnection(MiConexion)
        cnn.Open()
        sqlTrans = cnn.BeginTransaction()

        Try
        
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GrabaPago", cnn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Transaction = sqlTranPago
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gloClv_Session", clvSesion)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Efectivo", importeEfectivo)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cambio", importeCambio)
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        
            Dim Clv_FacturaSalida1 As Int64
            Dim cmd As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("GrabaFactura", cnn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Transaction = sqlTranPago
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Contrato", Contrato)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Clv_Session", clvSesion)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cajera", Cajera)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sucursal", Sucursal)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Caja", Caja)
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Tipo", Tipo)

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
            sqlTrans.Commit()

            GloClv_Factura = cmd.Parameters("@Clv_FacturaSalida").Value

            cnn.Close()
            cnn.Dispose()


        Catch ex As Exception
            sqlTrans.Rollback()
        End Try

    End Using



End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Deberias hacerlo todo dentro de un solo SP. No es buena practica realizar las transacciones desde el cliente.

Mira este SP, si falla una instrucción falla todo y se realiza el Rollback tran.

```
USE [Farmacia]
GO
/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[KardexMovimientosUpdSaldoProc]    Script Date: 13-04-2022 22:49:21 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- KardexMovimientosUpdSaldoProc 'VTSAL', 'SAL', 'Salida por venta xxx Boleta de venta N° yyy."', '100259', '1548452115', 1, 1, 'current.Usuario'

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[KardexMovimientosUpdSaldoProc]
(
    @idTipoMovimiento   char(5), 
    @Imputacion         char(3), 
    @Glosa              varchar(120), 
    @idProducto         varchar(15), 
    @Serie              varchar(50),
    @Cantidad           numeric(18,4), 
    @idBodega           int, 
    @Usuario            varchar(25)
)
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @StockTotal  DECIMAL(18,4)
    DECLARE @NuevoSaldo  DECIMAL(18,4)
    DECLARE @PrecioCosto DECIMAL(18,4)
    DECLARE @PrecioVenta DECIMAL(18,4)
    DECLARE @TasaIVA DECIMAL(5,2);

    BEGIN TRANSACTION

    --
    -- Obtener la tasa del IVA para el calculo del precio de venta
    --
    SET @TasaIVA = ISNULL((SELECT ValorIva from Parametros), 0) / 100;

    --
    --  Obtener el StockTotal diponible y calcula el nuevo saldo
    --
    SELECT @StockTotal   = StockTotal--,
            --@PrecioCosto = PrecioCosto,
            --@PrecioVenta = PrecioVenta
        FROM Kardex
        WHERE idProducto = @idProducto 
          AND idBodega   = @idBodega
    --
    -- Nuevo Saldo
    --
    SET @NuevoSaldo = @StockTotal - @Cantidad

    --
    -- Obtener el precio de costo y calcular el precio de venta
    --
    SELECT @PrecioCosto = ValorNeto,
           @PrecioVenta = ValorNeto * (1 + @TasaIva)
      FROM Lotes 
     WHERE idProducto = @idProducto 
       AND Serie      = @Serie

    --
    -- Actualizar el nuevo StockTotal del inventario
    --
    UPDATE Kardex 
       SET StockTotal = @NuevoSaldo
     WHERE idProducto = @idProducto 
       AND idBodega   = @idBodega

    IF(@@error!=0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR  20001 'KardexMovimientosUpdProc: No pudo se actualizar la tabla Kardex '
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN(1)
    END


    --
    --  Actualizar el saldo del lote, descuenta la cantidad del saldo disponible
    --
    UPDATE Lotes 
       SET Saldo = Saldo - @Cantidad
      FROM Lotes 
     WHERE idProducto = @idProducto 
       AND Serie      = @Serie
    IF(@@error!=0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR  20002 'KardexMovimientosUpdProc: No pudo se actualizar la tabla Lotes '
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN(1)
    END    


    --
    -- Insertar el movimiento de inventario y registrar los datos del movimiento
    --
    INSERT INTO dbo.KardexMovimientos
                (Fecha
                ,idTipoMovimiento
                ,Imputacion
                ,Glosa
                ,idProducto
                ,Serie
                ,CostoUnitario
                ,Cantidad
                ,Saldo
                ,Valor
                ,InventarioFinal
                ,idBodega
                ,Usuario)
            VALUES
                (GETDATE()
                ,@idTipoMovimiento
                ,@Imputacion
                ,@Glosa
                ,@idProducto
                ,@serie
                ,@PrecioCosto
                ,@Cantidad
                ,@StockTotal
                ,@PrecioVenta
                ,@NuevoSaldo
                ,@idBodega
                ,@Usuario)

    IF(@@error!=0)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR  20000 'KardexMovimientosUpdProc: No pudo se actualizar la tabla KardexMovimientos'
        ROLLBACK TRAN
        RETURN(1)
    END

    COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```